# Using LINQ Include after GroupBy and Take

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity Foo, which has a property "Type". 
I'm trying to group the data by Type and get 5 rows from each type. I created a class FooGroup which has a property Type and List. Meanwhile, each Foo is connected with 4 other entities and I'm trying to eager load them using Include

```
public class FooGroup() {
     public TypeEnum? Type{ get; set; }
     public List<FooViewModel> Foos{ get; set; }
}
```

My current logic is:

```
var foos = ctx.Foo; // ctx = DBContext
foos = foos.Include(x => x.Bar); // Include all other entities

var groups = foos
     .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
     .Select(x => new FooGroup()
          {
               Type = x.Key,
               Foos = x.Take(5).Select(foo => new FooViewModel(foo)).ToList()
          })
     .ToList();
```

There are no errors, but the Include is lost, because the query is reshaped by the group by. What's the best approach to keep the Include?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foos = foos.Include(x => x.Bar)`?

Comment: The include is in the results.  You need to enumerate through Foos. Yu may also want to use SelectMany.

Comment: Projection also kills the includes.

Comment: @juharr True, I changed it. I was changing my entities to foos and bars and missed that one. Not the actual problem though, it was correct in my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to first flatten (ungroup) the result (taking the desired number of rows of each group), *then* apply the includes, switch to LINQ to Objects context (in memory) and perform the grouping and final projection there:

```
var groups = ctx.Foo
     .GroupBy(x => x.Type) // Group
     .SelectMany(g => g.Take(5)) // Ungroup
     .Include(x => x.Bar) // Include all other entities
     .AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Objects
     .GroupBy(x => x.Type) // Group again     
     .Select(g => new FooGroup() // Project
     {
         Type = g.Key,
         Foos = g.Select(x => new FooViewModel(x)).ToList()
     })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed. Eventually I adopted the same idea that I might need to do a double grouping but didn't get it to work properly. Thank you.